# grep a file in gitlab ci with colon and space

Tags: linux, grep, gitlab, alpine-linux

i have a  file which contains a lot of text. there is one line in it which reads as -

```
     Total: 2 (UNKNOWN: 0, LOW: 0, MEDIUM: 0, HIGH: 2, CRITICAL: 0)
```

i need the values  HIGH: 2  and CRITICAL: 0 and check if the numbers against them are greater than zero.
I wrote a script in gitlab ci as:

```
   echo "if [ -n \"grep \"CRITICAL: [1-9]* \| HIGH: [1-9]*\" test || true\" ]"   >> script.sh
   echo "then"   >> script.sh
   echo "echo \"Issues found , HIGH and CRITICAL severity\" " >> script.sh
   echo "exit 1" >> script.sh
   echo "else">> script.sh
   echo "echo \"no critical or high severity issue found\" " >> script.sh
   echo "fi" >> script.sh
```

i couldnt use this as gitlab-ci.yml dont support a colon followed by space ": " i also tried using

```
   echo "if [ -n \"grep \"CRITICAL:[[:space:]][1-9]* \| HIGH:[[:space:]] [1-9]*\" test || true\" ]"
```

the above one dont error out but it fails to give any output. i am running the gitlab on Alpine 3.12.0. But the same script executes fine if i run it on a plain alpine linux instance manually ( ie not in gitlab pipeline)

Thanks in advance

Comment: `I wrote a script in gitlab ci` just write the script normally as an actual file and commit it.

Answer (score 0):

As `gitlab` supports `alpine` sh, this script should hopefully work.

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

high=$(grep -o 'HIGH[^,]*' input_file)
critical=$(grep -o 'CRITICAL[^)]*' input_file)

if [[ ${high//[A-Z:]} > 0 ]] && [[ ${critical//[A-Z:]} > 0 ]]; then 
    echo "Issues found , HIGH and CRITICAL severity"
elif [[ ${high//[A-Z:]} > 0 ]]; then 
    echo "Issues found , HIGH severity" 
elif [[ ${critical//[A-Z:]} > 0 ]]; then 
    echo "Issues found, CRITICAL severity" 
else echo "no critical or high severity issue found" 
fi
```

The script uses variables containing the output `HIGH: 2` and `CRITICAL: 0`.

The loop will first check if both values are greater than zero. if not, it moves on to the next conditions. If a value is greater than zero, it will output a message.

**Output**

```
$ ./tst.sh
Issues found , HIGH severity
```

Comment: Thanks for the input . i tried with file text - Total: 2 (UNKNOWN: 0, LOW: 0, MEDIUM: 0, HIGH: 0, CRITICAL: 0)   -but it always gives-  Issues found , HIGH and CRITICAL severity. Looking into it